# Symfony 3.4 forms: Pass variables from one type to another

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have two types. One is ProductType. The second is ProductFeaturesType.
ProductFeaturesType is a CollectionType inside ProductType.
I would like to pass my variable product from ProductType to ProductFeaturesType.

> EDITED

My objective is to do a condition in my ProductFeaturesType depending on one property of my product.

I tried the following:

**ProductType**

```
$builder
            ->add('productFeatures', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ProductFeaturesType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'product' => $product
            ))
        ;
```

It didn't work. I got the following error message:

> The option "product" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_add", "allow_delete", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "delete_empty", "disabled", "documentation", "empty_data", "entry_options", "entry_type", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "prototype", "prototype_data", "prototype_name", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".

Could you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception is telling you what's wrong in your code, **the option product is not a defined option** inside form builder declarations. If your intention is to save/update the product with the product-features you have already done that since you have the mapping information; MTO or MTM; in your entities and defined the collectionType in the form builder. When you submit the form symfony will set, "pass", the product entity in each of the features entities.
Just remove the product option an try to submit the form.

Hope it helps!

> EDITED

You only need to add a [form event listener](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) to your Type

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $event->getData(); // here you have all the data to be set which match with the data_class option of your type
            $event->getForm(); //here you have the form and you can manipulate it as you wish.
});
```

Comment: yes please update your question so my answer will be apropiate